# Using Best fit scale for atlas map with clipped boundary

Tags: qgis, print-composer, atlas

I'm using the atlas layout feature with a Map that has a clipped boundary.
Map is controlled by Atlas with a predefined (best fit) scale.
The map doesn't recognize that it's clipped and some of the current Atlas feature is obscured by the clip boundary.

See image below.

What the best way to resolve this?
Do I create a new field in the Atlas coverage layer for Scale?
Then change from Predefined Scale to fixed scale and set the scale the new field.

[image]

Comment: can you clarify what you mean by "The map doesn't recognize that it's clipped and some of the current Atlas feature is obscured by the clip boundary."?

Comment: Do you mean that part of the polygon is covered by design elements (scale bar)?